# how to combine calibration element to set HFRCOCTRL

Tags: embedded

I want to set HFRCO frequency.I have found the following  register called HFRCOCTRL the closes bitfiled i found is frequency range.
Using the calibration table ,how do i combine the two to set HFRCO to be 4Mhz?
Thanks.
https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/reference-manuals/efr32xg14-rm.pdf
[image]

[image]

Comment: You have roughly ten questions open about how to use various aspects of the same MCU. Some even have answers and you have not accepted them or continued to work towards getting an answer you could accept. The answers would be most likely found in the MCU documentation, such as datasheet, reference manual, application notes, and example codes. Changing the MCU clock rate requires a specific sequence to allow proper operation, and it is hard to believe that documentation how to do it can't be found. There might even be a library or startup code genetator that already does this for you.

Comment: Hello Just me, I understood the prescaling and enabling,I am stuck with the first main clock .I want to set HFRCO to be 4Mhz.
I did a research in the referench manual and found this register called CMU_HFRCOCTRL. and i found the table of calibration.
Every number in the calibration table is 24bits but our register is 32 bit.Where do i put those 24bits?

I put in the first 24bits of the register
Thanks.